# Missing custom page templates from "Template to design mapping" in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore SXA 1.8

I have created a Tenant Folder , a Tenant and a Site using SXA. I have created custom page templates for the site. I am trying to map a custom page template to a Page Design but am unable to find the custom page template.

My templates:

[image]

I can see a lot of feature templates available but not the page templates under the tenant:

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

I Managed to Fix this issue , the appropriate Sit template location for the site should set

1. Open the '/sitecore/content/{Tenant}/{Tenant Site}/Settings' item.
2. Choose 'Project/{Appropriate Tenant}' as a value for the 'Templates location' field in the 'Site Configuration' section.
3. Save the item.

Answer (score 2):

Your template needs to inherit (base template) from the "Page" template to get into that list. The specs of the base template you need (in 1.7.1 - probably not changed):

- ID: `{3F8A6A5D-7B1A-4566-8CD4-0A50F3030BD8}`
- Path: `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Content/Page`

It does not have to be an immediate base template - but somewhere in the base template tree this one has to be found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gatogordo , The template inherits the Page base template you have mentioned , but this this does not seem to solve the problem , am i missing anything else?

Comment: the template mapping source seems to be correct query:$templates||query:$pageDesigns//*[@@templatename='Page Design'] , but the lookup name displays all feature templates as well which is wrong

Comment: The query does seem correct indeed, but the list of templates is completely wrong. You might need a deep dive - open a Support ticket and send them a package of all your templates and the site...